# remove array entry with empty values

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have an array with a lot of empty values and I want to remove them from the array....

```
    NSMutableArray *entry = [self.selectedRow allValues];

for (int i = 0 ; i < [entry count] ; i++) {

    NSLog(@"count: %@", [entry objectAtIndex: i]);
    NSLog(@"point: %@", [selectedRow valueForKey:[entry objectAtIndex:i]]);
    if([[selectedRow valueForKey:[entry objectAtIndex: i]] length] < 2){
        [selectedRow removeObjectAtIndex: i];
    }
}
```

the `< 2` is because there are some values there not really empty.....

for some reason `[entry valueForKey:[entry objectAtIndex:i]]]` is empty

and i get the exeption `-[__NSCFDictionary removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7021510` but there is no dictionary involved ther are only arrays.

and when i count down `for (int i = [entry count -1; i = 0; i--]){` the loop isn't even called?!?

I hope someone can help me with that....

**EDIT:**

Is not what initialy wanted but some how it works better that way...
I check the length for the valueForKey when I parse the file so i reduce the file size for more then the half and it works pretty good.....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *entry = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.selectedRow allValues]];
```

because `[self.selectedRow allValues]` likely returns an `NSArray` you can't just pretend it's Mutable.

OH.  and furthermore `self.selectedRow` looks like an `NSDictionary`.  Try `removeObjectForKey:` instead.

Comment: selectRow is an NSMutableArray...
and I hade a typo its `[entry valueForKey:[entry objectAtIndex:i]]]` which is empty `[entry count]` gives the right count....

Comment: or `NSMutableArray *entry = [[self.selectedRow allValues] mutableCopy];`

Answer (score 0):

Should be,

```
for (int i = [entry count] -1; i > 0; i--]){ }
```

And try,

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < [selectedRow count]; i++) {
    if([[selectedRow objectAtIndex: i] count] < 2){
        [selectedRow removeObjectAtIndex: i];
    }
}
```

Comment: well now I get to the loop...

but still the same exeption.

Comment: you should be clearer, about what is in the array? Is it array of array? or something else?

Comment: that depends from which view I come.
in one case it's an array of array.
in the other it's an array of array which is filled with a dictionary.....